# ThreadPoolExecutor CPU 100% load

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I needed to execute my workers on several cores because I have a possibility to separate my task to several tasks manually, so I limply need to use `newFixedThreadPool`, but my worker raises a 100% CPU loading. If it using the whole cores for it it's okay, but it's working only 2x faster than without thread pool, so seems that it using it without sense.

I tried to use plain `newFixedThreadPool`:

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool (Runtime.getRuntime ().availableProcessors ());

for (int i = 0; i < Runtime.getRuntime ().availableProcessors (); i++)
    pool.execute (new MyTask (this));
```

and `ThreadPoolExecutor` with passed queue:

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<> ();

for (int i = 0; i < Runtime.getRuntime ().availableProcessors (); i++)
    queue.add (new MyTask (this));

ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor (Runtime.getRuntime ().availableProcessors (), Runtime.getRuntime ().availableProcessors (), 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);

pool.prestartAllCoreThreads ();
```

And result still the same.

MyTask is trivial and written for example:

```
    protected static class MyTask implements Runnable {
        
        @Override
        public void run () {
            
            int i = 0;
            
            while (true)
                i++;
            
        }
```

After running workers without `ThreadPoolExecutor` CPU loading is normal and varies for about 10-20%. So what will be wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing exactly what is calculated. Please [edit] the post and add a [MRE].

Comment: You are blaming `ThreadPoolExecutor` when in reality it is most probably your worker code that is causing your CPU to go to 100%.

Comment: @jbx but it not loads without it

Comment: You have an infinite loop without any blocking code. So it will take 1 core (or half of it if you have a hyperthreading CPU) and use as much as possible of it. If you use a thread pool it will start multiple workers and load all cores, using 100% of your CPU. Not sure what you were expecting instead.

Comment: Wow. Yes, that's what I've asked about. I need to sort out a bunch of random numbers in endless loop and find needed, so I can sepearate this task to several because none of them needed to connect with others. It all differs.

Comment: @Acuna it is still not clear what your task actually is. But to distribute your task onto multiple cores you need to have some strategy how to distribute your work into chunks. Maybe you might want to use a Fork-Join Pool to have a work-stealing algorithm implementation, so that workers take bits of the problem and then the result is joined together. Without knowing your actual problem its hard to say.

Comment: @jbx I want simply divide my tasks with infinite loops on several cores. Because I thought than Java can it out of the box.

Comment: @Acuna yes you can but you need to decide how to split the task, how will one thread know what to do and not repeat the same thing another task is doing. Java can't know what you are trying to achieve, so you need to decide how to subdivide the task and distribute it.

Comment: @jbx I can simply split my task to several tasks which every of them goes over several numbers which is not needed to connect with others tasks

Comment: @Acuna so you should notice a speed up if you split the numbers and use a threadpool. Alternatively you could look at using a ForkJoinPool which conceptually splits big tasks into smaller ones and then distributes them to different workers, and then joins back the results from each worker. The pattern is sort of designed for your use case.

Comment: @jbx ForkJoinPool is for separation tasks in proccess, but I simply need to separate it on start only and work with it in infinite loop. But I found a Java-Thread-Affinity library (https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Thread-Affinity) for it which separate thread pools even with infinite loop to the separated cores - one task per core, it's exactly what  I need, really recommend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is not clear exactly what you are trying to find out, you have to keep this in mind.

A single thread will only make use of one (virtual) core at a time. It is usually backed by a single OS kernel process (I say usually because there are a lot of fancy stuff some frameworks and VMs are doing with Virtual Threads and what not lately).

When the thread blocks (to do I/O or wait for something, or sleeps, or there is an explicit call to `yield()`), it relinquishes the CPU core to another thread.

So running a simple infinite loop on a single worker thread will only make use of 1 core. Which is why you observe 10% to 20% loading (depending on how many virtual cores you have on your machine).

On the other hand, if you create a thread pool of as many cores as you have, all doing the same infinite loop on separate threads, each will take one available core and use it, which will drive your CPU loading to 100%.

They are completely separate workers, so you can't expect your first worker to complete faster or anything of that sort. If anything it will be slower, because you have exhausted all CPU resources, and the OS and even the JVM now will compete to do its own thing, like run the garbage collector etc.

Comment: If by “fancy stuff” you mean [*Project Loom*](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/loom/Main), do not conflate that with [Green Threads](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_thread) from the early days of Java. For one thing, Green Threads were entirely limited to a single host OS thread whereas virtual threads in Project Loom can be carried on a number of host OS threads.

Comment: @BasilBourque I wasn't exclusively talking about "Green Threads" as such, just wanted to point out that although in my explanation I talked about a Thread-to-OS process mapping, that might not always be the case. There lots of variants of user-space concurrency models (see Golang). Project Loom's Virtual Threads (I think originally called Fibers) are different from the old Java Green Threads (as you say they were pinned to one OS process). Maybe "green thread" was the wrong term (in the old days when we did it manually in C with `setjmp` and `longjmp` we just called them 'user-level threads')

Answer (score 3):

## A CPU-bound task is bound to take all of the CPU

You have an infinite loop that does nothing more than run calculations. That code never blocks. That is, the code never stops to wait on externalities. For example, the code never contacts a database, never writes to storage, and never makes a call over the network.

With nothing to do but calculations on the CPU, such a task is considered to be [CPU-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound). Such a task will use 100% of a CPU core.

You multiply this task, to have one such task per core for every core in your machine. So all cores are pushed to 100%. Likely your machine will get hot, fans will spin, and CPU will throttle.

This seems rather obvious. Perhaps you should edit your Question to explain why you expected a different behavior.

Tip: Avoid loading *all* your cores with CPU-bound tasks. The [OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) has many processes that need to run, and other apps need to run.

Comment: Wow. Yes, I did't know it's working like so, so my problem is what I simply want to use all my cores to theoretically made my tasks faster. Or I've missed something?